# Retornar campo calculado por generator no Firebird (FireDAC)

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Possuo TFDQuerys criadas em tempo de execução com o propósito de inserir registros em meu banco de dados.

**Tabela:**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLETESTE (
    ID  INTEGER
);

SET TERM ^ ;

/* Trigger: TABLETESTE_BI */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TABLETESTE_BI FOR TABLETESTE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
as
begin
  if (new.id is null) then
    new.id = gen_id(gen_tableteste_id,1);
end
^

SET TERM ; ^
```

**Código:**

```
   Query1.Open('select * from TABLETESTE where 1 = 2');
   Query1.Append;
   Query1.Post;
   showmessage(Query1.FieldByName('id').AsString); //Retorna em branco, esperado retornar o próximo id
```

**Dúvida:**

É possível fazer com que a query receba automaticamente os valores alterados por procedures/triggers no banco de dados ao efetuar o post da mesma?

Comment: vc pode chamar `Query1.Refresh` (não lembro de cabeça se o FireDac tem o método RefreshRecord, se tiver use) para atualizar os campos antes do showmessage() ou o que vc precisar fazer com o campo alterado na trigger